# incrementing a pointer inside a function

Tags: c, pointers, increment, operator-keyword, dereference

I was writing a program in C just for fun (and exercise) and I stumbled upon this behavior which I don't understand...
Incrementing a pointer within a function is not possible with the `++` operator

```c
void fn(void **p)
{
    *p++;
    // other options like *p+=1 or ++*p work, but I dont understand why...
}
```

Could someone explain (for a noob ;) ) why this doesn't work ? I am very curious.

Comment: Operator precedence. It's being interpreted as `*(p++)`.  Use `(*p)++`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are passing a pointer to the function indirectly through a pointer to it.

So to increment the original pointer you need to dereference the pointer that points to the original pointer and then increment it.

For example

```
++*p;
```

Otherwise this expression statement

```
*p++;
```

does not increment the original pointer because the statement is equivalent to

```
*( p++ );
```

due to the operator precedences.

In fact the above statement is equivalent to

```
p++;
```

because the result of the operator * is not used.

On the other hand, even if you will write the statement correctly (according to the logic)

```
++*p;
```

it does not make a sense because you may not increment a pointer of the type `void *` (though some compilers for the backward compatibility allow such an operation with pointers of the type `void *` similarly to pointers of the type `char *`) because the type `void` is an incomplete type and can not be completed.

Comment: It may also be worth noting that incrementing a `void*` is undefined behavior under the C-standard, even if your compiler lets you get away with it

Comment: @WillisHershey Thanks. I have appended the answer.